# Any improvements you can suggest, to these two 555 circuits?

Tags: led, 555

This is a continuation of my original question that got put on hold...
[Any IC, to control a LED with a single push-button (ON,OFF,FLASH)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455965/any-ic-to-control-a-led-with-a-single-push-button-on-off-flash)

I have come up with two solutions that work for me:

- a push button ON/OFF,
- and a push button ON/OFF Blinker.

Can anyone suggest any improvement to these [two 555 circuits]

[v2 here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.0005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0A165+512+-16+544+-16+6+9.68141044536359e-13%0Ar+704+48+704+144+0+330%0Aw+640+-96+640+16+0%0A162+704+144+704+224+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+704+48+640+48+0%0Aw+576+-48+576+-96+0%0Aw+640+-96+576+-96+0%0Aw+640+48+640+32+0%0Aw+640+32+464+32+0%0Ar+464+32+464+144+0+50000%0Aw+512+80+512+112+0%0Aw+512+112+512+144+0%0Aw+512+144+464+144+0%0A209+464+144+464+224+0+0.000009999999999999999+4.84080204146257e-8+1%0Aw+464+224+576+224+0%0Ag+736+224+736+256+0%0Aw+608+144+608+224+0%0Aw+256+-112+160+-112+0%0Aw+256+-112+256+-48+0%0Ar+160+80+160+224+0+10000%0Aw+160+224+288+224+0%0Ar+160+-112+160+-16+0+10000%0Aw+160+224+96+224+0%0Aw+160+80+160+-16+0%0Aw+192+80+160+80+0%0Aw+192+80+192+112+0%0Aw+320+-112+256+-112+0%0Aw+320+16+320+-112+0%0Aw+368+48+368+-48+0%0Aw+320+48+368+48+0%0Aw+416+224+288+224+0%0Aw+288+144+288+224+0%0A165+192+-16+224+-16+6+1.0000002769487293e-13%0As+96+-16+160+-16+0+1+true%0A209+96+-16+96+224+0+0.000001+1.0276939053330989e-13+1%0Ar+96+-112+96+-16+0+100000%0Aw+96+-144+96+-112+0%0Aw+368+-144+96+-144+0%0Aw+368+-96+368+-144+0%0Aw+368+-96+368+-48+0%0Aw+416+-112+320+-112+0%0Ar+416+64+416+224+0+330%0Aw+416+-112+416+-64+0%0At+368+-48+416+-48+0+1+-4.9999999999999+-3.218962811175718e-11+100%0Aw+736+-112+416+-112+0%0Av+736+224+736+-112+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+416+-32+432+-32+0%0Ac+576+144+576+224+0+1e-9+2.1526418759634697e-11%0Aw+576+224+608+224+0%0Aw+416+-32+416+64+0%0Aw+432+-32+432+-96+0%0Aw+432+-96+576+-96+0%0Aw+608+224+704+224+0%0Aw+416+224+464+224+0%0Ag+464+624+464+672+0%0Aw+256+352+160+352+0%0Aw+256+352+256+416+0%0Ar+160+544+160+624+0+10000%0Aw+160+624+288+624+0%0Ar+160+352+160+448+0+10000%0Aw+160+624+96+624+0%0Aw+160+544+160+448+0%0Aw+192+544+160+544+0%0Aw+192+544+192+576+0%0Aw+320+352+256+352+0%0Aw+320+480+320+352+0%0Aw+368+512+368+416+0%0Aw+320+512+368+512+0%0Aw+416+624+288+624+0%0Aw+288+608+288+624+0%0A165+192+448+224+448+6+1.0000397602170666e-13%0As+96+448+160+448+0+1+true%0A209+96+448+96+624+0+0.000001+1.0000397602172222e-13+1%0Ar+96+352+96+448+0+100000%0Aw+96+320+96+352+0%0Aw+368+320+96+320+0%0Aw+368+368+368+320+0%0Aw+368+368+368+416+0%0Aw+416+352+320+352+0%0Ar+416+432+416+528+0+330%0Aw+416+352+416+400+0%0At+368+416+416+416+0+1+-4.9999999999999+-0.00010304479162843449+100%0Aw+464+352+416+352+0%0Aw+464+624+416+624+0%0A162+416+528+416+624+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Av+464+624+464+352+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ax+90+302+321+305+4+24+ON/OFF%5CsCONSTANT%0Ax+91+-165+293+-162+4+24+ON/OFF%5CsBLINKER%0Ar+864+352+864+432+0+10000%0Ar+864+432+864+528+0+10000%0A209+864+528+864+608+0+0.000001+4.994164413790416+5%0As+864+528+928+528+0+1+true%0Aw+928+528+1024+528+0%0Aw+864+608+960+608+0%0Aw+960+608+960+464+0%0At+992+448+960+448+0+1+-4.591201031377277+0.40296338241313834+100%0Aw+864+432+960+432+0%0Av+1264+608+1264+352+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+992+448+1024+448+0+1000%0Ar+1024+528+1088+528+0+1000%0Ar+1024+448+1024+528+0+10000%0Ar+1024+528+1024+608+0+470000%0Aw+960+608+1024+608+0%0At+1056+400+1024+400+0+-1+4.1843556657587575+-0.41267511634389464+100%0Aw+1024+384+1024+352+0%0Aw+1024+352+864+352+0%0Aw+1024+416+1024+448+0%0Aw+1024+352+1120+352+0%0Aw+1120+352+1200+352+0%0Aw+1120+400+1120+448+0%0Ar+1120+448+1120+512+0+100000%0At+1088+528+1120+528+0+1+-4.150679327961463+0.394528575717677+100%0Aw+1120+544+1120+608+0%0Aw+1024+608+1120+608+0%0Aw+1120+608+1200+608+0%0Ag+1264+608+1264+624+0%0Af+1120+512+1200+512+33+1.5+0.02%0Aw+1200+496+1200+352+0%0Aw+1200+352+1264+352+0%0A162+1200+560+1200+608+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+1200+608+1264+608+0%0Ar+1120+400+1120+352+0+1000000%0Aw+1056+400+1120+400+0%0Ar+1200+528+1200+560+0+330%0Aw+1408+144+1504+144+0%0Aw+1408+144+1440+144+0%0Ac+1408+96+1408+144+0+1e-9+0.21537609861595577%0Av+1536+144+1536+-112+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+1440+96+1440+144+0%0Ag+1536+144+1536+176+0%0Aw+1296+144+1408+144+0%0A209+1296+64+1296+144+0+0.000009999999999999999+3.087986297822936e-11+1%0Aw+1344+64+1296+64+0%0Aw+1344+32+1344+64+0%0Ar+1296+-16+1296+64+0+50000%0Aw+1472+-16+1296+-16+0%0Aw+1472+0+1472+-16+0%0Aw+1472+-96+1408+-96+0%0Aw+1504+0+1472+0+0%0A162+1504+48+1504+144+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+1504+0+1504+48+0+330%0A165+1344+-64+1376+-64+6+6.175849072668972e-16%0Ar+1248+-16+1248+64+0+330%0Aw+1056+-64+1120+-64+0%0Ar+1120+-64+1120+-112+0+1000000%0Aw+1200+-112+1232+-112+0%0Aw+1200+32+1200+-112+0%0Af+1120+48+1200+48+33+1.5+0.02%0Aw+1024+144+1120+144+0%0Aw+1120+80+1120+144+0%0At+1088+64+1120+64+0+1+-4.150679327961308+0.3945285757177126+100%0Ar+1120+-16+1120+48+0+100000%0Aw+1120+-64+1120+-16+0%0Aw+1120+-112+1200+-112+0%0Aw+1024+-112+1120+-112+0%0Aw+1024+-48+1024+-16+0%0Aw+1024+-112+864+-112+0%0Aw+1024+-80+1024+-112+0%0At+1056+-64+1024+-64+0+-1+4.184355665758662+-0.41267511634395326+100%0Aw+944+144+1024+144+0%0Ar+1024+64+1024+144+0+470000%0Ar+1024+-16+1024+64+0+10000%0Ar+1024+64+1088+64+0+1000%0Ar+976+-16+1024+-16+0+1000%0Aw+864+-32+944+-32+0%0At+976+-16+944+-16+0+1+-4.591201031377243+0.4029633824131735+100%0Aw+944+144+944+0+0%0Aw+864+144+944+144+0%0Aw+928+64+1024+64+0%0As+864+64+928+64+0+1+true%0A209+864+64+864+144+0+0.000001+4.994164413790434+5%0Ar+864+-32+864+64+0+10000%0Ar+864+-112+864+-32+0+10000%0At+1248+-16+1248+-64+1+1+-4.180898278192756+0.49603757388328007+100%0Aw+1232+-112+1232+-80+0%0Aw+1536+-112+1232+-112+0%0Aw+1232+-64+1232+-80+0%0Aw+1408+-96+1264+-96+0%0Aw+1264+-96+1264+-64+0%0Aw+1200+64+1248+64+0%0Aw+1296+144+1120+144+0%0Ax+864+305+1119+308+4+24+ON/OFF%5CsCONSTANT%5CsB%0Ax+859+-159+1085+-156+4+24+ON/OFF%5CsBLINKER%5CsB%0Ax+1252+128+1344+131+4+12+BLINK%5Cs%5Cs%5Cs%5CsSPEED%0Ax+421+208+513+211+4+12+BLINK%5Cs%5Cs%5Cs%5CsSPEED%0Ab+845+-127+880+163+0%0Ab+850+338+878+627+0%0Ax+830+178+941+181+4+12+DEBOUNCE%5CsSPEED%0Ax+830+643+941+646+4+12+DEBOUNCE%5CsSPEED%0Aw+1472+-32+1472+-96+0%0Aw+1504+144+1536+144+0%0Aw+704+224+736+224+0%0A)

Managed to remove the 555 for the ON/OFF functionality.

[image]

Comment: No, becuase you have provided no constraints or goal, making this nothing more than a continuation of your existing question.  The main problem here seems to be that you aren't willing to take time to understand the operation, norms, and rules of this site.

Comment: Further, any real "light source" system would for efficiency use a current mode driver (ie, not an BJT and a resistor).  What you've got is maybe viable for an blinking *indicator* or an elementary hobby project, but not practical for any viable *use*.

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.